# Keep text order when read and write a file

Tags: c#, richtextbox

Hi I've made a program that generate a txt file given some parameters, here is an example of output.txt

```
APSF-COMPANY = hi
APSF-CERTIFY = 12345678
APSF-CERTIFY = 12345678
APSF-CERTIFY = 12345678
APSF-CERTIFY = 12345678
APSF-CERTIFY = 12345678
```

When I go to generate the file I've made a method to crypt characters in the file, so the real output.txt is

```
UdgZAWcadUbm4Q4|}
UdgZAWYfh]Zm4Q4EFGHIJKL
UdgZAWYfh]Zm4Q4EFGHIJKL
UdgZAWYfh]Zm4Q4EFGHIJKL
UdgZAWYfh]Zm4Q4EFGHIJKL
UdgZAWYfh]Zm4Q4EFGHIJKL
```

Here's the method to crypt

```
public string crypt(string tmp)
{
    string result = "";
    foreach (var c in tmp)
    {
        if (c == 'z') result += 'a';
        else if (c == 'Z') result += 'A';
        else result += (char)(((int)c) +20);
    }

    return result;
}
```

When I go to decrypt the file (putting the content of the output.txt in a richTextBox) it isn't the same.
Method for decrypt

```
public string decrypt(string tmp)
{
    string result = "";

    foreach (var c in tmp)
    {
        result += (char)(((int)c) - 20);
    }

    return result;

}
```

And here is the piece of code for putting the content in the richTextBox

```
richTextBox1.Text = decrypt(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

And here what happens in the richTextBox:

**Wrong**

[image: Wrong]

And here how it has to be:

**Right**

[image: Right]

(I think the problem is the 'enter' character)

Comment: Yes, work through each line and encrypt it, not encrypt the line feeds as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned by BugFinder don't decrypt the entire text in one blow because of the `\n` character which you apparently decrypt. Decrypt it line by line :

```
string[] allLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("YourFile.txt");
foreach (var line in allLines)
{
    richTextBox1.AppendText(decrypt(line) + Environment.NewLine);
}
```